# React Native update value on another component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

1I´m trying to display on Example component a value, my countdowns loops every 1 minute and adds +value to `this.state.count`

`countdown 1 - adds +1 to count.
 countdown 2 - adds +2 to count. 
 countdown 3 - adds +3 to count.`

Every 1 minute, on Example component, count should increment +3+2+1.

The problem is the nesting, How am i gonna update Example value with this nesting?

[image]

(**Countdown**) component, which ticks for a minute and adds +1 to count.

```
export default class Countdown1 extends React.Component {
    state = {
       seconds: 1000 * 60,
       count: 1,
    };

render(){
      return(
            <TimerCountdown
            //initialSecondsRemaining={1000 * 60}
            initialSecondsRemaining={this.state.seconds}
            onTimeElapsed={() => this.setState({seconds: 1000 * 60, count: Example.state.count+1})}
            allowFontScaling={true}
            style={styles.clock}
            />
           );
```

(**Example**) which i want to display the count value.

```
 export default class Money extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        count: 1,
    };
}

 render() {

return (
        <View>
         <Text style={styles.text1}>{this.state.count}</Text>
        </View>
   );
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

Choose one. The list is ordered by recommendation.

1. Use state management library as mobx or redux. (https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx)
2. Use React hooks for management your store (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)
3. Call props.function for triggering parent's function. (Example: https://gist.github.com/sebkouba/a5ac75153ef8d8827b98)

Answer (score 0):

I think the real solution is to redesign your component hierarchy.  What's Example component doing?

Comment: Example is a component which displays points. Everytime a countdown loops, it adds points to the display, also tried :

`onTimeElapsed={() => {
   this.setState({seconds: 1000 * 60}),
  Money.setState({ count: Money.state.count+1 })
}}` but no sucess.